# Texmaker "you do not have read permission to this file" imac

Tags: texmaker, mac, opentype

I am using texmaker to open a .tex file and a .cls file on a computer. I have tried to open the same files in another computer and I get the error message:
"you do not have read permission to this file"

However, if I try to open a different .tex file all works fine.
Any idea what is happening?

Comment: What TeX Distribution are you using? How did you install it? Where are the files you’re trying to open?

Comment: The files are in a Dropbox folder, that is why I can access from different computers. Texmaker 5.0.3

Comment: What are the permissions of the Dropbox folder sub-folders and files? By the way, typesetting files in a Dropbox folder can be a problem.

Comment: Read and write. I have no problem open them in another pc. Why could it be a problem?

Comment: I have restarted the computer and now I can open the .tex files and they appear empty. Also I cannot open the pdfs.

Comment: What happens if you copy the files to your Desktop? This sounds like a Dropbox problem.

Comment: Wait... does the folder have only read/write? It should read/write/execute by you.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Does Finder show that now? It never used to ....

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. No, you need to use `ls -al ~` in Terminal to see the full permissions.